# Use '${}' as useState value Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The second ${tickettype} come from props

```
const tickettype = location.state.tickettype;

[`${tickettype}`]: `${tickettype} + ${ticketnumber}`
```

But ${tickettype} is showing a data like that : "ticketadcopy" At the base ticketadcopy is a constant called in usestate from the firebase database

```
  const [tadcopy, setTAdcopy] = useState('');
  const [tvideos, setTVideos] = useState('');
  const [tdescriptions, setTDescriptions] = useState('');
  const [tthumbnails, setTThumbnails] = useState('');
```

For the moment, the function arrives in my database as "the value of the props ${tickettype} + a number from ${ticketnumber},

What I would like is that since ${tickettype} will return a value of type "ticketvideos", "ticketadcopy".... that it considers ${tickettype} as the constant tadcopy for example and that when I import to firebase, it gives me :

For example tadcopy = 5 and ${ticketnumber} = 3

5 + 3 = 8

For the moment, it shows me "tadcopy + 3

[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: What is the relation with `tickettype` and `tadcopy`? What data type is `tadcopy`?

Comment: tadcopy is an amount of ticket available (number), tickettype will be the name of state like (tadcopy, tvideos, tdescriptions...)

Comment: if i understood you right did you try
 [`${tickettype}`]: `${tickettype + ticketnumber}`

Comment: I would recommend keeping all the types in an object as single state, then you can do `state[tickettype ]`

Comment: result => "tvideos10" text from tickettype and number is ok